# Is it a good idea to call await Task.Delay(0) to make an method "awaitable" in an ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have the following interface and two of its implementations:

```
public interface ITokenCache
{
    string GetToken(string key);
    string SetToken(string key, string value);
    void DeleteToken(string key);
}

public class InMemory : ITokenCache
{          
    // Implementation using IMemoryCache.
}

public class Redis : ITokenCache
{
    // Implemetation using Redis.
}
```

I'm using APIs from `Microsoft.StackExchange.Redis` when working with redis and they support asynchronous methods. But `IMemoryCache` don't. Therefore, I can make the methods defined in `ITokenCache` "looking awaitable" such as,

```
public async Task<string> GetToken(string key)
{
    return _memoryCache.Get(key) as string;
}
```

If I choose this way, I get multiple compiler warnings as I await nothing in the `InMemory` implementation. When looking for a solution, one answer suggested using `await Task.Delay(0)` in the `InMemory` implementation. (It appeared as only a workaround to suppress compiler warning.)

But also, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/best-practices?view=aspnetcore-7.0) recommend not to use methods such as `Task.Run` in an ASP.NET Core Web Application.

What would be the better way to fulfill my requirement? Should I just ignore the compiler warnings?

Comment: No. You aren't making it awaitable either. If you want to return a ready-made value, use `Task.FromResult()`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? For starters, memory caching is already available. The RAM-or-Redis abstraction is provided [by IDistributedCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0). There are extensions built on top of it that [simplify the Cache-aside pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/caching-abstraction-improvements-in-aspnetcore/) using either RAM or Redis

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to give a abstraction from the caching for my controllers and any other services that use caching and inject either InMemory or Redis implementation to the DI container.

Comment: The abstraction already exists, it's IDistributedCache. Its two most common *providers* are in-memory and Redis. What you want is available and *expected* by other packages. A NuGet package that wants to use caching will ask for an `IDistributedCache` instance, not your own custom implementation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos now I understand what you meant. btw, thank you for the resources :-)

Answer (score 3):

The quick-fix in this situation is to `await` something that is already completed, e.g., `await Task.CompletedTask;`

However, I prefer just suppressing the warning with a `#pragma`. This gives the code more clarity: it is in fact a synchronous implementation of an asynchronous method (which is exactly what the warning is saying).

The problem with `Task.FromResult`-based approaches is that they do not properly handle exceptions. In a task-returning method, the expectation is that exceptions are placed on the returned task.

Comment: In this case one should ask why mimic IDistributedCache instead of actually using it?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware there was already an abstraction and in-memory implementation of this. It does sound like the OP is reinventing that.

Comment: Aside: Not a huge fan of the `MemoryDistributedCache` name, since there is such a thing as a "distributed memory cache" but this is not that; it's is a single-node in-memory implementation of the `IDistributedCache` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without marking `async` by returning a [Task.FromResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=net-7.0) containing your value. This is a will still return a `Task`, so your method is awaitable, but as there's nothing to await the `Task` is simply marked as completed.

For your `void` return method, if you need it to be awaitable you can return [Task.CompletedTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in having an await here. You can just use `Task.FromResult` and return it here like this:

```cs
public Task<string> GetToken(string key)
{
    return Task.FromResult(_memoryCache.Get(key) as string);
}
```